# Page render without CSS to some users

Tags: asp.net, caching, gzip

Im having a big problem and i have no idea how to solve it. I made a class that combine, minify, gzip and cache my styles and scripts. It works fine. 2 days ago i got a report that some people are seeing the website without css. How can i see the site perfect well and some people dont? A friend told me it can be the browser of these people doesnt accept gzip.

Another thing that can be, i created my own extensions (.cssh and .jsh), but i transmit then with content type text/css and text/javascript so i guess its not a problem.

Any help is apreciated. Sorry for my bad english :/

Link to site: http://www.curriculoautentico.com.br

Comment: Can you post a link to this site so we can see?

Comment: Browsers that don't accept GZIP shouldn't matter, provided you are actually checking `Accept-Encoding` and sending the data appropriately.  File name extensions don't matter either, as long as your `Content-Type` header is correct.  It has to be something else.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer. The problem was with the compression with gzip. I made the cache gziped already, so users who have browser that dont accept gzip cant see the css. I had to cache the CSS and JS minified but not gziped.